# How to interpolate between two non-consecutive points in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to interpolate a range of values between two known points.
So, the data is like -

```
    C     D    E   F
12 2019 2020 2021 2022 
13  67   -     -    2
```

I am trying to use index to calculate using forecast -

```
=FORECAST(D12,C13:INDEX(C13:F13,1,4),C12:INDEX(C12:F12,1,4))
```

but its not working. I am new in excel. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It works with me. Which cell did you use for the calculation? Is the cell within the range you reference? https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ePQ.jpg

Comment: I am calculating at D13.

Comment: Then you have a circular reference (formula referencing to it's own cell. Place it in - for instance D14 and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to avoid circular reference in D13 (this array formula should be compatible with Excel >= 2013)

```
=FORECAST(D12:E12;TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<x><a>"&TEXTJOIN("</a><a>";TRUE;$C13:C13)&"</a>"&REPT("<a>FALSE</a>";COUNTA($C$12:$F$12)-(COUNTA($C13:C13)+1))&"<a>"&$F13&"</a>"&"</x>";"//a"));$C$12:$F$12)
```

Output :

[image: Interpolation]